# roscore not working (upstream packages)

Tags: ros, rosdep, roslauch, roscore, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running roscore gives this error:

```
... logging to /home/atul/.ros/log/1bd30c60-bb61-11ea-8a96-39cbecce8d08/roslaunch-atul-18118.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Resource not found: roslaunch
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/noetic/share
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I was following the beginners tutorials from http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials. Initially, roscore was working and I was able to go through all the tutorials. When I tried to run roswtf from http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Getting%20started%20with%20roswtf tutorial, it said that roswtf not found and can be installed by sudo apt install python3-roswtf. I did that and while executing

```
$ roscd rosmaster
$ roswtf
```

from the tutorial, I got a warning and it suggested me to run sudo rosdep init and then rosdep update. After doing both, there were no warnings and roswtf gave the output as shown in the tutorial. But for the next part of the tutorial, it said to run roscore, but since that time, I'm getting this error and roscore is not starting. Even roscd was not working, so I ran sudo apt install ros-noetic-rosbash which fixed the roscd problem.

This is what I get after running env | grep ROS

```
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/share
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
ROS_DISTRO=noetic
```

Please help me

I looked up in /var/log/apt/history.log and found out that running `sudo apt install python3-rosdep2` removed 49 packages, which seems to have caused all the problems:

```
Start-Date: 2020-07-01  10:14:06
Commandline: apt install python3-rosdep2
Requested-By: atul (1000)
Install: python3-rosdep2:amd64 (0.18.0-1)
Remove: ros-noetic-rospy:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.061557), ros-noetic-nodelet:amd64 (1.10.0-1focal.20200529.061908), ros-noetic-rqt-common-plugins:amd64 (0.4.9-1focal.20200615.143035), ros-noetic-qt-gui-cpp:amd64 (0.4.1-1focal.20200612.013014), ros-noetic-rqt-bag:amd64 (0.4.13-1focal.20200613.043147), ros-noetic-rqt-shell:amd64 (0.4.10-1focal.20200613.043315), ros-noetic-rqt-dep:amd64 (0.4.10-1focal.20200613.043407), ros-noetic-rosbag:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.063008), ros-noetic-rqt-launch:amd64 (0.4.8-1focal.20200613.043540), ros-noetic-rqt-gui:amd64 (0.5.2-1focal.20200613.042207), ros-noetic-rqt-reconfigure:amd64 (0.5.3-1focal.20200615.142604), ros-noetic-rqt-publisher:amd64 (0.4.9-1focal.20200613.042853), ros-noetic-rosunit:amd64 (1.15.4-1focal.20200529.055729), ros-noetic-rqt-action:amd64 (0.4.9-1focal.20200613.043629), ros-noetic-rosnode:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.063935), ros-noetic-rqt-gui-py:amd64 (0.5.2-1focal.20200613.042533), ros-noetic-rqt-msg:amd64 (0.4.9-1focal.20200613.043546), python3-rosdep-modules:amd64 (0.19.0-1), ros-noetic-rqt-graph:amd64 (0.4.14-1focal.20200613.043132), ros-noetic-rostest:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.062051), ros-noetic-rostopic:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.063544), ros-noetic-roslib:amd64 (1.15.4-1focal.20200529.055538), ros-noetic-rosbag-storage:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.062400), ros-noetic-rqt-bag-plugins:amd64 (0.4.13-1focal.20200613.043434), ros-noetic-rosmsg:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.063551), ros-noetic-rospack:amd64 (2.6.2-1focal.20200529.055340), ros-noetic-rqt-srv:amd64 (0.4.8-1focal.20200613.043637), ros-noetic-rqt-py-common:amd64 (0.5.2-1focal.20200613.042121), ros-noetic-rosservice:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.063848), ros-noetic-rosbash:amd64 (1.15.4-1focal.20200529.055532), ros-noetic-rqt-top:amd64 (0.4.9-1focal.20200613.043325), ros-noetic-roslaunch:amd64 (1.15.7-1focal.20200529.061835), ros-noetic-rqt-web:amd64 (0.4.9-1focal.20200613.043402), ros-noetic-actionlib:amd64 (1.13.1-1focal.20200529.064105), ros-noetic-rqt-logger-level:amd64 (0.4.11-1focal.20200613.043252), ros-noetic-image-transport:amd64 (1.12.0-1focal.20200529.064210), ros-noetic-ros-tutorials:amd64 (0.10.1-1focal.20200529.062752), ros-noetic-rqt:amd64 (0.5.2-1focal.20200613.042744), ros-noetic-rqt-gui-cpp:amd64 (0.5.2-1focal.20200613.042207), ros-noetic-rqt-image-view:amd64 (0.4.15-1focal.20200613.043008), ros-noetic-rqt-topic:amd64 (0.4.12-1focal.20200613.043300), ros-noetic-rqt-py-console:amd64 (0.4.9-1focal.20200613.043249), ros-noetic-rospy-tutorials:amd64 (0.10.1-1focal.20200529.062434), ros-noetic-rqt-console:amd64 (0.4.11-1focal.20200613.043501), ros-noetic-rqt-service-caller:amd64 (0.4.9-1focal.20200613.042931), ros-noetic-rqt-plot:amd64 (0.4.12-1focal.20200613.043159), ros-noetic-turtlesim:amd64 (0.10.1-1focal.20200529.061639), ros-noetic-pluginlib:amd64 (1.13.0-1focal.20200529.060526), ros-noetic-dynamic-reconfigure:amd64 (1.7.0-1focal.20200529.064038)
End-Date: 2020-07-01  10:14:45
```

As for `sudo apt install python3-roswtf`, it did the following:

```
Start-Date: 2020-07-01  10:12:40
Commandline: apt install python3-roswtf
Requested-By: atul (1000)
Install: python3-rosservice:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5, automatic), python3-rostopic:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5, automatic), python3-rosmsg:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5, automatic), python3-roswtf:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5), python3-rosnode:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5, automatic)
End-Date: 2020-07-01  10:12:49
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356158/roscore-not-working-(upstream-packages)/) by [AtulKarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/56310/atulkarn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> it said that roswtf not found and can be installed by `sudo apt install python3-roswtf`

It's unfortunate, but following that advice -- which comes from Ubuntu itself btw -- you've most likely broken your ROS install.

The package you've installed is an [UpstreamPackage](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages), not the version which is part of ROS Noetic.

Note the name of the package you installed: `python3-roswtf`.

The regular package is called `ros-noetic-roswtf`.

As the upstream version depends on other upstream packages *and* conflicts with the regular ROS packages, the regular ROS packages get uninstalled. This is most likely the cause of `roslaunch` no longer working.

You'll want to reinstall the regular ROS packages.

I expect things to start working again after that.

---

Edit:

> I had also run `sudo apt install puthon3-rosdep2` which seems to have removed all the packages. It removed 49 packages.

then it might be prudent to just try a reinstall. Unless you can figure out from the `apt` log which packages specifically were removed.

---

Edit 2:

> I looked up in `/var/log/apt/history.log` and found out that running `sudo apt install python3-rosdep2` removed 49 packages, which seems to have caused all the problems:

you should be able to restore your ROS install to a working state by reinstalling those packages.

`apt` will likely complain about those packages conflicting with the upstream packages, but you should just let it remove those.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-01**:
For a related discussion, see [“upstream packages” becoming increasingly a problem](https://discourse.ros.org/t/upstream-packages-becoming-increasingly-a-problem/10902) on ROS Discourse.

**Comment by [AtulKarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/56310/atulkarn/) on 2020-07-01**:
Do I need to reinstall the whole ROS distro or only specific packages?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-01**:
That will depend on how much was uninstalled when you installed `python3-roswtf`. I don't know. Only you can find out.

You could take a look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` and see what was installed and uninstalled. Note: log entries are appended to that file, so recent operations will be at the end of the file.

**Comment by [AtulKarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/56310/atulkarn/) on 2020-07-01**:
I did sudo apt install ros-noetic-roslaunch and now roscore is working. Thanks for the advice. I also checked the log files. lnstalling python3-roswtf installed :

```
Start-Date: 2020-07-01  10:12:40
Commandline: apt install python3-roswtf
Requested-By: atul (1000)
Install: python3-rosservice:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5, automatic), python3-rostopic:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5, automatic), python3-rosmsg:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5, automatic), python3-roswtf:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5), python3-rosnode:amd64 (1.14.3+ds1-11ubuntu5, automatic)
End-Date: 2020-07-01  10:12:49
```

**Comment by [AtulKarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/56310/atulkarn/) on 2020-07-01**:
I had also run sudo apt install puthon3-rosdep2 which seems to have removed all the packages. It removed 49 packages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-01**:
Please add this to your *original question text*, not here in comments.

Use the `edit` button/link to edit your original question.

**Comment by [AtulKarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/56310/atulkarn/) on 2020-07-01**:
Thanks a lot for your help. I reinstalled all the packages and everything looks good now.